.NET 8 solution does not build because "ResolveTargetingPackAssets" task failed unexpectedly (XmlException)
I have a .NET 8 solution with a few projects, all targeting .NET 8.0, but I can't build it and get this error:

The "ResolveTargetingPackAssets" task failed unexpectedly.
System.Xml.XmlException: '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid
character. Line 1, position 1.    at
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)    at
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowInvalidChar(Char[] data, Int32
length, Int32 invCharPos)    at
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()    at
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()    at
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri, LoadOptions options)
at
Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolveTargetingPackAssets.AddItemsFromFrameworkList(FrameworkListDefinition
definition, IBuildEngine4 buildEngine4, List1 referenceItems, List1
analyzerItems)    at
Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolveTargetingPackAssets.Resolve(StronglyTypedInputs
inputs, IBuildEngine4 buildEngine)    at
Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolveTargetingPackAssets.ExecuteCore()
at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute()    at
Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Execute()    at
Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()

This is a fresh install of Windows 11 and VS 2022 Community, and the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets that was marked as the issue, was first taken from C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\9.0.100, which is weird. I installed the latest .NET 8 SDK (as it was missing), added some global.json files to force version 8.0.404.
The build still fails, but at least the targets file is coming from the correct .NET version folder... I already did clean, rebuild, clear nuget storage, deleting bin/obj files, deleting nuget.config from AppData, still it doesn't work. I have no idea what is wrong...

.NET 8 works. Randomly deleting stuff will only make things worse. How was the project created? How did it end up in your machine? The error complains about a NUL character at the start of the file. Either a csproj file was damaged or the file is saved as UTF16 without a BOM, and the build tools are trying to process it as UTF8

Corrupted FrameworkList.xml perhaps: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/15863  Avoid rebooting the machine after installing .net, go looking for better anti-malware.

The solution was cloned from a private git repository from azure. I didn't change the source code or any file, other than an appsettings.Development.json, but I tried reverting the changes as well. I'll check the encoding of the csproj files and the FrameworkList.xml later/tomorrow.

So it seems that FrameworkList.xml in C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref\8.0.11\data only contains NUL data, so white space? Same for the other files in that folder, PackageOverrides.txt and PlatformManifest.txt. I tried a repair on the installed ASP.NET Core 8.0.11 - Shared Framework and it asked for the installer executable... selected the aspnetcore-runtime-8.0.11-win-x64.exe and did the repair, but nothing changed.

The solution was to do a repair with the .NET 8 SDK installer.

The issue is resolved by updating Visual Studio to version 17.12.3.
